# Trying to dynamically set interface based off of enum value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, types, typescript-generics

Hey all I'm trying to dynamically set a style interface to a type like this:

```
type IListStyles = {
    [LIST_TYPE.ADD_ACTIONABLE]: IListItemAddActionableStyle;
    [LIST_TYPE.SUPERVALUE]: IListItemSupervalueStyle;
}

enum LIST_TYPE {
  ADD_ACTIONABLE = "ADD_ACTIONABLE",
  SUPERVALUE = "SUPERVALUE",
}

export interface IListItem<T extends LIST_TYPE> {
  style?: IListStyles[T];
  type: T;
```

Buuut I'm getting that T can't be used to index `IListStyles` has anyone done something like this before?

Comment: What version of typescript are you using (since it works in the [latest version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgMgSwM7AMqgDYSVAvFAbwFgAoKcqAbThlQBUB9OgTQAUBRAOgEEARXhtwDCdGAHkActwBCcdgF0AXLEQoYwCAFtuAEx3cAxsAQB7AHYBDAEZZ0ILAG5SFKjXpM2XVAFUOAJQA1bjhvBWV4ZGB1LVQAV0gAJwA3CwxYiDtHUgBfUlIEMw0EgDMLA2gItQ1tPUNjc2tbTGgCbKcSAqLS8pVI6M04xJS0jObCNrySCDNYzSg3RhYOQmcoPgFhUUkZOTwoACJ1wRFxKVl2fYAaVZ9-IJD2Pf3b9kDg0KucyYgADzATBLAKCdCAlMoVVRRaoAHjoUF+GjMOhwCw8HAAfCsyFAUPYIAB+cKQzLYSh0eTtcigSDKOjtXIkUgGcwoKDAIl9GGopZcI6bU47diY-DEbFU8AQZTczw8fjHLZnOTXMU45rKVpfRkkZlmJAmLCcDAmADmAApgABKBxAA))

Answer (score 0):

you can also use an object instead of enum :

```
const LIST_TYPE = {
    ADD_ACTIONABLE: "ADD_ACTIONABLE",
    SUPERVALUE: "SUPERVALUE",
} as const;

type TLISTTYPE = typeof LIST_TYPE[keyof typeof LIST_TYPE];

interface IListItemAddActionableStyle {
    a: string;
}
interface IListItemSupervalueStyle {
    b: string;
}

type TListStyles = {
    [LIST_TYPE.ADD_ACTIONABLE]: IListItemAddActionableStyle;
    [LIST_TYPE.SUPERVALUE]: IListItemSupervalueStyle;
};

export interface IListItem<T extends TLISTTYPE> {
    style?: TListStyles[T];
    type: T;
}

const resu: IListItem<"ADD_ACTIONABLE"> = {
    type: "ADD_ACTIONABLE",
    style: { a: "dskqldq" },
};

console.log({ resu });
```